# Python Histogram using matplotlib on top words

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am reading a file and calculating the frequency of the top 100 words. I am able to find that and create the following list:

```
[('test', 510), ('Hey', 362), ("please", 753), ('take', 446), ('herbert', 325), ('live', 222), ('hate', 210), ('white', 191), ('simple', 175), ('harry', 172), ('woman', 170), ('basil', 153), ('things', 129), ('think', 126), ('bye', 124), ('thing', 120), ('love', 107), ('quite', 107), ('face', 107), ('eyes', 107), ('time', 106), ('himself', 105), ('want', 105), ('good', 105), ('really', 103), ('away',100), ('did', 100), ('people', 99), ('came', 97), ('say', 97), ('cried', 95), ('looked', 94), ('tell', 92), ('look', 91), ('world', 89), ('work', 89), ('project', 88), ('room', 88), ('going', 87), ('answered', 87), ('mr', 87), ('little', 87), ('yes', 84), ('silly', 82), ('thought', 82), ('shall', 81), ('circle', 80), ('hallward', 80), ('told', 77), ('feel', 76), ('great', 74), ('art', 74), ('dear',73), ('picture', 73), ('men', 72), ('long', 71), ('young', 70), ('lady', 69), ('let', 66), ('minute', 66), ('women', 66), ('soul', 65), ('door', 64), ('hand',63), ('went', 63), ('make', 63), ('night', 62), ('asked', 61), ('old', 61), ('passed', 60), ('afraid', 60), ('night', 59), ('looking', 58), ('wonderful', 58), ('gutenberg-tm', 56), ('beauty', 55), ('sir', 55), ('table', 55), ('turned', 54), ('lips', 54), ("one's", 54), ('better', 54), ('got', 54), ('vane', 54), ('right',53), ('left', 53), ('course', 52), ('hands', 52), ('portrait', 52), ('head', 51), ("can't", 49), ('true', 49), ('house', 49), ('believe', 49), ('black', 49), ('horrible', 48), ('oh', 48), ('knew', 47), ('curious', 47), ('myself', 47)]
```

After getting this list, I want to draw histogram using matplotlib. I am trying something as below, but I am not able to draw a proper histogram.

**My question:** How do I pass the total frequency to the graph? All of my bars are at the same height right now. And even the bin center is not correct. How should I pass data to the ax.hist method on below code? I am trying to update the example from http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/api/histogram_demo.html.

```
totalWords = counts.most_common(100)
print(totalWords)
for z in range(len(totalWords)):
    words.append(totalWords[z][0])

x = np.arange(len(words))
#print x
i, s = 100, 15

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)


bincenters = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])

y = mlab.normpdf(bincenters*1.00, i, s)
l = ax.plot(bincenters, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)

ax.set_xlabel('Words')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_xlim(50, 160)
ax.set_ylim(0, 0.04)
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You need histogram or bar chart? In histogram, the x-axis is a continuous variable over real numbers. Bar chart is categorical - like individual words.

Comment: Thank you for answering Aditya. I am looking for Histogram only and not bar chart.

Comment: I think this is for an exam

Comment: @user3314492 tell me difference between histogram and bar chart according to your knowledge.

Comment: @Detroitteatime seems so. I'll see how he replies to my comments only then we can be clear or else we'll begin flagging.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want. This code produces a bar chart with each bar representing individual words and vertical axis provides the frequency of word in your text.

The counts array you provided is not sorted as I had expected though.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counts = [('test', 510), ('Hey', 362), ("please", 753), ('take', 446), ('herbert', 325), ('live', 222), ('hate', 210), ('white', 191), ('simple', 175), ('harry', 172), ('woman', 170), ('basil', 153), ('things', 129), ('think', 126), ('bye', 124), ('thing', 120), ('love', 107), ('quite', 107), ('face', 107), ('eyes', 107), ('time', 106), ('himself', 105), ('want', 105), ('good', 105), ('really', 103), ('away',100), ('did', 100), ('people', 99), ('came', 97), ('say', 97), ('cried', 95), ('looked', 94), ('tell', 92), ('look', 91), ('world', 89), ('work', 89), ('project', 88), ('room', 88), ('going', 87), ('answered', 87), ('mr', 87), ('little', 87), ('yes', 84), ('silly', 82), ('thought', 82), ('shall', 81), ('circle', 80), ('hallward', 80), ('told', 77), ('feel', 76), ('great', 74), ('art', 74), ('dear',73), ('picture', 73), ('men', 72), ('long', 71), ('young', 70), ('lady', 69), ('let', 66), ('minute', 66), ('women', 66), ('soul', 65), ('door', 64), ('hand',63), ('went', 63), ('make', 63), ('night', 62), ('asked', 61), ('old', 61), ('passed', 60), ('afraid', 60), ('night', 59), ('looking', 58), ('wonderful', 58), ('gutenberg-tm', 56), ('beauty', 55), ('sir', 55), ('table', 55), ('turned', 54), ('lips', 54), ("one's", 54), ('better', 54), ('got', 54), ('vane', 54), ('right',53), ('left', 53), ('course', 52), ('hands', 52), ('portrait', 52), ('head', 51), ("can't", 49), ('true', 49), ('house', 49), ('believe', 49), ('black', 49), ('horrible', 48), ('oh', 48), ('knew', 47), ('curious', 47), ('myself', 47)]
words = [x[0] for x in counts]
values = [int(x[1]) for x in counts]
print words
mybar = plt.bar(range(len(words)), values, color='green', alpha=0.4)

plt.xlabel('Word Index')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Word Frequency Chart')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

You can see the graph following a ziphian curve (power law curve). Modify the code to suit your need.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering @Aditya. But I am looking for Histogram here . That is why I was not sure what to pass on .hist method.

Comment: Dude histogram is on sorted numerical quantities. Did you have a look at the graph my code generates? That's exactly what you want. In hist() you've to tell the 'bins' - which are blocks of real numbers on the x-axis. Where are real numbers in the words?

Comment: Well @user3314492 what's different in this graph from your expectations?

Comment: This is awesome. How do I adapt this to add the words on the X axis @Aditya?

Comment: Also how did you get it so there are only labels every 20 increments?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what you want to graph, and how relevant the matplotlib demo you are adapting *actually* is.

I'll run through some options, and try and answer your specific questions in each case:

- Using the matplotlib demo, you only need to give ax.hist the list of word frequencies 
  `x = words[n][1]`
  ,but this just gives you the relative frequency of the different frequencies... so most of the words occur <100 times, while a couple of words occur much more frequently. This is why your code above returns a histogram of equal bars, because you are giving ax.hist the numbers from 0 to 99 once each. Note that this approach doesn't show the individual words
- Otherwise, I think you want a bar chart with each bar labelled as a different word.

This worked for me.

```
words = [('test', 510), ('Hey', 362), ("please", 753), ('take', 446),     ('herbert', 325), ('live', 222), ('hate', 210), ('white', 191), ('simple', 175),     ('harry', 172), ('woman', 170), ('basil', 153), ('things', 129), ('think', 126), ('bye', 124), ('thing', 120), ('love', 107), ('quite', 107), ('face', 107), ('eyes', 107), ('time', 106), ('himself', 105), ('want', 105), ('good', 105), ('really', 103), ('away',100), ('did', 100), ('people', 99), ('came', 97), ('say', 97), ('cried', 95), ('looked', 94), ('tell', 92), ('look', 91), ('world', 89), ('work', 89), ('project', 88), ('room', 88), ('going', 87), ('answered', 87), ('mr', 87), ('little', 87), ('yes', 84), ('silly', 82), ('thought', 82), ('shall', 81), ('circle', 80), ('hallward', 80), ('told', 77), ('feel', 76), ('great', 74), ('art', 74), ('dear',73), ('picture', 73), ('men', 72), ('long', 71), ('young', 70), ('lady', 69), ('let', 66), ('minute', 66), ('women', 66), ('soul', 65), ('door', 64), ('hand',63), ('went', 63), ('make', 63), ('night', 62), ('asked', 61), ('old', 61), ('passed', 60), ('afraid', 60), ('night', 59), ('looking', 58), ('wonderful', 58), ('gutenberg-tm', 56), ('beauty', 55), ('sir', 55), ('table', 55), ('turned', 54), ('lips', 54), ("one's", 54), ('better', 54), ('got', 54), ('vane', 54), ('right',53), ('left', 53), ('course', 52), ('hands', 52), ('portrait', 52), ('head', 51), ("can't", 49), ('true', 49), ('house', 49), ('believe', 49), ('black', 49), ('horrible', 48), ('oh', 48), ('knew', 47), ('curious', 47), ('myself', 47)]
wordsdict = {}
for w in words:
    wordsdict[w[0]]=w[1]

plt.bar(range(len(wordsdict)), wordsdict.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(wordsdict)), wordsdict.keys())

plt.show()
```

Comment: THank you for answer @TMrtSmith. I am looking for Histogram only. Not bar chart. I want graph same or similar to what I have given in example.